# In swap array[i] = array[j] TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python

The code is supposed to show a video frame using the laptop webcam as a source, all is working fine, so after it shows the colors calibration window , it has to show next is the video frame,

I know that this "Tuple" issue is related to lists initialization, I tried some modifications based on stackoverflow, but unfortunately,I couldn't recognize what is it exactly.

Error :

> File ~\Downloads\Gesture-Controlled-Mouse-master\Gesture-Controlled-Mouse-master\main - Copy.py:39 in swap array[i] = array[j] TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Here is the code section that has the issue :

```
def swap( array, i, j):
temp = array[i]
array[i] = array[j]
array[j] = temp
```

here is the main code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
import time

blue_range = np.array([[88,78,20],[128,255,255]])
yellow_range = np.array([[21,70,80],[61,255,255]])
red_range = np.array([[158,85,72],[180 ,255,255]])
# Prior initialization of all centers for safety
b_cen, y_pos, r_cen = [240,320],[240,320],[240,320]
cursor = [960,540]
# Area ranges for contours of different colours to be detected
r_area = [100,1700]
b_area = [100,1700]
y_area = [100,1700]
# Rectangular kernal for eroding and dilating the mask for primary noise removal 
kernel = np.ones((7,7),np.uint8)
# Status variables defined globally
perform = False
# 'nothing' function is useful when creating trackbars
# It is passed as last argument in the cv2.createTrackbar() function
def nothing(x):
    pass
def swap( array, i, j):
    array = list(array)
    temp = array[i]
    array[i] = array[j]
    array[j] = temp
```

The whole code :  [Main code](https://github.com/alokm014/Gesture-Controlled-Mouse/blob/master/main.py)

some assistance would guide me , [Output with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZikT.png) Thank you in advance

Comment: The type error is spot on here: the operation `array[j] = ...` is **not** supported for a tuple. One way around this is writing  `array = list(array)` before trying the item assignment.

Comment: You haven't put enough code in the question for us to reproduce, so it's mostly a guess: It looks like what you are calling `array` is actually a tuple. Tuples are immutable;  you cannot change them.

Comment: do you mean after `def swap( array, i, j):`  I write : `array = list(array)` ?

Comment: Maybe not @Kraigolas — it looks like this code is depending on the side effect of modifying the input. Making a copy of the tuple won't work for that. In fact, there's no way for this function to work as designed with a tuple as input.

Comment: Yes I just tried that modification , it shows : `TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`

Comment: @med we can't see your code without logging into pythonanywhere. And you shouldn't depend on outside links to code in questions anyway. Edit the question to give people enough code to reproduce this error.

Comment: @Mark, Okay I will , some seconds please

Comment: No error for me

Comment: this is the section I guess has the error,the main code is long ,

Comment: It says I need to be signed in... (when entering the link to the 'main code')

Comment: Please check this , for the main code : [link](https://github.com/alokm014/Gesture-Controlled-Mouse/blob/master/main.py)  , I am working on it

Comment: This code defines the `swap` function but never _calls_ it...

Comment: @JohnGordon, I see, if you can please check the main code in the link , in comments section

Comment: I don't see where you use your `swap` function. However variable swapping in python is done rather easy: `x, y = y, x`

Comment: @MSH Actually `swap`  function is used after, it's in the main code in the link

Comment: @MSH `swap` function is used twice in the code , so the 2nd time it's in the line 116 like that :`swap( contour, i, j)`

Comment: at first it was the `_,contour, _ = cv2.findContours( mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)`  issue , but I fixed it into : `contour, _ = cv2.findContours( mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)`  , and now I am facing Tuple problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I understand the problem:

You got the error because you tried to swap elements of `tuple`. Which is an **unchangeable** variable type. So you would get an error saying you cannot alter a `tuple`.

Next you decided to change the type of the `tuple` to `list`. Which would work. The only problem is it will not.

One can categorize python object in two:

`Immutable` and `Mutable`.

### `Immutable`

Immutable objects are kind of objects you can't alter/change/update. Such as `str`, `int`, `tuple`.

### `Mutable`

Mutable objects are kind of objects you can alter/change/update. Such as `list`, `dict`.

When an object is passed to a function:

1. The object would be copied to function, if the object is immutable
2. A reference to object would be given if the object is mutable:

Example:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]

def alter_mutable(obj):
    del obj[0]

print(lst)
alter_mutable(lst)
print(lst)
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 4]
```

See the `lst` changed outside the function, because a reference was given to function and altering it in the function changed it everywhere.

```
num = 2

def alter_immutable(obj):
    obj += 1

print(num)
alter_immutable(num)
print(num)
```

Result:

```
2
2
```

Here `num` did not change. Because a copy of it was given to function and change it inside the function did not effect it outside.

The tuple you were given to the function will be copied and changing it to a list, altering it is not effecting the data outside the function.

### What can be done?

You can return the object and use it:

```
def swap( array, i, j):
    array = list(array)
    array[i], array[j] = array[j], array[i]
    return tuple(array)
```

Since we changed the function, the usage must change as well.

Usage:

```
contour = swap(contour, i, j)
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH that was exactly what it's needed , it's worked perfectly, I can now arrive to the frame vedio mode, but the webcam is flipped now, I see myself filpped , I am trying to correct some numbers for the frame

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the problem.

Firstly, when calling the function: `cv2.findContours()` to assign to `contour`, the return value of the function is a `Tuple`, thus trying to swap elements creates an error.

Secondly,
If you want to swap the values anyway there are several options:

- copying tuple into a list and changing it
- casting tuple to list
- and probably more

And, there's a better way to swap as described in the comments:

```py
def swap(array, i, j):
    array[i], array[j] = array[j], array[i]
    return array
```

This is a valid way to swap between variables

Comment: I tried this `temp, array[j] = array[i], temp`  and it shows the error:  `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'temp' referenced before assignment`

Comment: Could you please write it how it should be exactly

Comment: The Error tells you what the problem is... but yes, I will write the function

Comment: I apprciate it , but I don't know why it still showing :  `in swap
    array[i], array[j] = array[j], array[i]`   `TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: what about `temp`  it was in the Tuple : `temp = array[i]` Line 38 in the main code